# LEFT JOIN SQL but distinct

Tags: sql

I Have 2 tables,

A.Table Sales

```
Code | qty_sales Values
A    | 10
B    | 20
```

B. Table Master

```
Code | Style
A    | AA10
A    | AA12 
B    | BB10
```

And I want the result like this :

```
Code | Style | qty
A    |  A10  | 10
B    |  BB10 | 20
```

I just want to get one of the 2 style for code A

Comment: "LEFT JOIN SQL but distinct" your title solves it by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing the last answer by **Gordon Linoff**

I just change "m.style" to "c.style".

```
select s.code, c.style , s.qty_sales
from sales s join
 (select m.code, max(m.style) as style
  from master m
  group by m.code
 ) c
 on s.code = c.code;
```

I agree you will need a "rule" to get just one register of Master table.
I the example above by Gordon Linoff used the MAX command.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways in different databases, but here is one:

```
select s.code, c.style, s.qty_sales
from sales s join
     (select m.code, max(m.style) as style
      from master m
      group by m.code
     ) c
     on s.code = c.code;
```

This is ANSI standard code.  It does not choose an arbitrary style; it chooses the maximum (alphabetically).

A `LEFT JOIN` is not needed because the codes match in the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

without subquery:

```
select m.code, min(m.style) as style, min(s.qty_sales) as qty_sales
from master m join sales s on s.code=m.code
group by m.code
```